# Question on probability of an ordered choice of letters from a larger word

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Four letter words will be made from the letters in the word *BARNEY*. No repetition of letters, and Y is not considered a vowel. What is the probability that two vowels will be side by side in the word?

I'm completely stuck on this question.

Comment: Do you know how many total four-letter words can be made from BARNEY?

Comment: Yeah, 6P4 = 360

Comment: That's a good start; it's what you want for the denominator. For the numerator, figure out how many words you can make from BARNEY with side-by-side vowels.

Comment: I tried considering the two vowels as a single letter, i.e, (5P4 / 6P4) which did not give me the correct answer.

Comment: Think of building words with the vowels already in them, like in Rebecca's answer below. Thinking of the vowels as a single letter isn't a bad idea, but it's a letter you're forced to use, so you don't want it to be part of the pool you're choosing from.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: There are two vowels `A` and `E`.  So 4-letter words with them side by side have one of the $6$ follows forms:

```
AE--
-AE-
--AE
EA--
-EA-
--EA
```

Given any of these forms, how many ways can we add in the consonants?  This gives the total number $N$ of 4-letter words with `A` and `E` side by side.  And the probability will be $N/^6 P_4=N/360$.